# Running application from desktop takes too much time

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-7

I have a very strange situation with my wpf application. When I run it from Program Files or C directory everything is fine, but when I try to do this from Desktop than application needs about 60 seconds to start. I have no idea why. Did someone meet such problem?

Comment: maybe the application is trying to locate resources that are in different path because the start directory has changed

Comment: I found clue here, I will check this when I have time: http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/folder-virtualization-concepts-windows-vista